# Calculate the line integral $ \oint\limits_C e^{x+y} \, dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Calculate the line integral $ \oint\limits_C e^{x+y} \, dy$ over the part of lemniscate: $ (x^2 + y^2)^2 = x^2 - y^2, x \ge 0 $

I tryed the straight way: $ x = r \cos \phi, y = r \sin \phi $. Then lemniscate is $ r^2 = \cos 2\phi $ and $ y = \sqrt{\cos 2\phi}\sin \phi $, $ dy = \cos \phi \sqrt{\cos 2\phi} - \frac{\sin 2\phi}{\sqrt{\cos 2\phi}} $, hence

$$ \oint\limits_C e^{x+y} \, dy = \int\limits_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} e^{\sqrt{\cos 2\phi}(\cos \phi + \sin \phi)} (\cos \phi \sqrt{\cos 2\phi} - \frac{\sin 2\phi}{\sqrt{\cos 2\phi}}) \, d\phi $$

that seems too difficult to calculate.

Also I tryed to use Green's theorem, but I faced the same problem...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If make $x=\cosh t$ and $y=\sinh t$.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran Perhaps I misunderstand your intention, but that curve has trace a hyperbola, not a lemniscate.

Comment: I think you can use Green's theorem.

Comment: @HenryW How Green's theorem can help? I got $ \oint\limits_C e^{x+y} \, dy = \iint\limits_\Omega e^{x+y} \, dxdy $, where $ \Omega $ enclosed by this part of lemniscate. Is it easer to calculate?